# For each activity, show the volunteer highest number of points

Tags: sql

```html
CREATE DATABASE E_volunteerSy;

USE E_volunteerSy;
CREATE TABLE Participate_In
(  V_ID INT(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  Ename  CHAR(20),
  POINTS INT(255),
        AName CHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Participate_In
values 
(1001,'Name1',10,'A'),
(1002,'Name2',3,'A'),
(1003,'Name3',11,'B'),
(1004,'Name4',3,'B'),
(1005,'Name5',4,'B');
```

how can i wright a query that return the highest point for AName A and AName B.
AName meant activity name .

Comment: Very simple query,show what you tried

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AName, MAX(POINTS) AS Points FROM Participate_In GROUP BY AName
```

> **demo:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b8ea6/1/0

Answer (score 1):

This query will display the highest points for all the activities

```
SELECT Aname, MAX(points) 
FROM Participate_In
GROUP BY Aname
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select the top record by pointsw for each AName value

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AName ORDER BY  POINTS DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM Participate_In
) Sub 
WHERE RowNum = 1
```